# SelectedItem not updating when item removed from bound ObservableCollection WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am having trouble with a ListView updating the SelectedItem.
The ListView is bound to an ObservableCollection and there is a button which will remove the SelectedItem from that observable collection.

**ListView**

```
        <ListView x:Name="GroupList"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReport, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}"
                  SelectionChanged="GroupList_SelectionChanged">
```

**Button**

```
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Content="Remove"
                Command="{Binding RemoveSelectedCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GroupList, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

In the code behind I have a function to help debug the ListView. It shows the SelectedItem and it's index.

```
private void GroupList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(((ListView)sender).SelectedItem);
  Debug.WriteLine(((ListView)sender).SelectedIndex);
}
```

The ViewModel is relatively simple:

```
public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ReportData> reports;

    private ReportData selectedReport;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.RemoveSelectedCommand = new Command<ReportData>(this.RemoveSelectedFromGroup);
    }

    public ICommand RemoveSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ReportData> Reports
    {
      get => this.reports;
    }

    public ReportData SelectedReport
    {
      get => this.selectedReport;
      set => SetProperty(ref this.selectedReport, value);
    }

    private void RemoveSelectedFromGroup(ReportData report)
    {
      if (report != null)
      {
        this.RemovedReports.Add(report);
        this.Reports.Remove(report);
      }
    }
}
```

INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in NotifyPropertyChangedBase and works correctly.

SelectedItem and SelectedIndex update as expected before I click the button to remove an item. However after I remove an item, SelectedItem does not update (stays as the item that was just removed) and SelectedIndex always equals -1. The actual ListView does visually update (the removed Item is gone/no longer displayed), but any subsequent item that is selected is not reflected by the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex properties.

Since the ObservableCollection is clearly updating the ListView via the binding, I do not understand why the SelectedItem cannot also be updated once the previously selected item is removed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code as best I could and on removing the selected item I did observe a break-point get hit on SelectedReport.set in which the provided value was null.  I am not able to reproduce your issue.  The only suggestion I can offer is to try to set the *IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem* property on the listview to true.

Comment: The `SelectedItem` should be set to `null` when `SelectedIndex` is set to `-1`. What makes you think it doesn't? Did you try to bind to these properties in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this behavior seems to be because I was adding the report to another collection before removing it from the Reports collection.

I don't see this behavior anymore when I remove it from one collection, before adding it to another.

I'm not sure why this is like this - Maybe retaining some reference in the SelectedItem property.

I no longer have this issue, but I don't fully understand why.